# ActionListener set on an EpandableListView Adapter is Ignored

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have an `ExpandableListView` adapter that I use as Navigation Drawer Menu

In my main class to initialize the drawer I use something like

```
   ...
   mAdapter = new NavMenuExpamdableAdapter(this, items);
   mDrawerList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
   if (mDrawerList != null)
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
```

Since the `ExpandableListView` is used as navigation drawer, I cannot invoke the listener from the adapter class, so I use `mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());` to add a listener in the main class of the App.

The problem is that: in the main the method

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ExpandableListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            String text = "menu click... should be implemented";
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            System.out.println("OK");

        }

    }
```

seems completely ignored

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ActionListener set on an EpandableListView Adapter is Ignored

If you want to register click events for `ExpendableListView`, you should use methods:

- [OnChildClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html) to handle child click events
- [OnGroupClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener.html) to handle group click events

for handling click events. OnItemClickListener **is not working here** (item clicks are captured by the list itself to open child elements so listener never be called), sorry.